# $PS4 in bash - how can I reproduce the "level of indirection" behavior mentioned in the GNU docs?

Tags: bash

I'm reading the [GNU docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html), and I see the following sentence as part of the definition of `PS4`:

> The first character of the expanded value is replicated multiple times, as necessary, to indicate multiple levels of indirection. The default is ‘+ ’.

I interpret this to mean that I will see a `+` symbol for each level of abstraction in my code.  I wanted to reproduce this behavior in my shell, so I wrote the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function baz() {
  echo "inside baz"
}

function foo() {
  echo "inside foo";
  baz;
}

function bar() {
  echo "inside bar";
  foo;
}

set -x;

bar;
```

Since `bar` calls `foo`, and `foo` calls `baz`, I had expected up to 3 levels of indirection, and therefore I expected to see something like the following (or similar) as output:

```
+ bar
+ echo 'inside bar'
inside bar
++ foo
++ echo 'inside foo'
inside foo
+++ baz
+++ echo 'inside baz'
inside baz
```

However, that's not what I see.  Instead, I see:

```
+ bar
+ echo 'inside bar'
inside bar
+ foo
+ echo 'inside foo'
inside foo
+ baz
+ echo 'inside baz'
inside baz
```

Am I mis-understanding what "level of indirection" means in this context, or am I just failing to reproduce said levels of indirection correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The indirection is not related to functions as you have observed, but rather relates to `eval`, as this example shows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
echo 1
eval "echo 2"
eval 'eval "echo 3"'
```

this should emit something like

```
+ echo 1
1
+ eval 'echo 2'
++ echo 2
2
+ eval 'eval "echo 3"'
++ eval 'echo 3'
+++ echo 3
3
```

And, as muru points out, also sourced files:

```
$ cat code
echo help
source code
$ bash -x code
```

Hopefully your <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is ready and warmed up...

Comment: also command substitutions, `set -x; echo $(echo $(echo foo))` would show e.g. `+++ echo foo` etc. Oh, another answer said that already.

Answer (score 8):

As the currently accepted answer tells you, the level is related to the nesting level which is increased by eval and sourcing. It is also increased by command substitution.

```
PS4='+ '
echo hello > world
set -x
wc -l $(ls -tc | head -1)
```

gives

```
++ ls -tc
++ head -1
+ wc -l world
1 world
```

If you are interested in the function depth then you can use the `FUNCNAME` array. For example

```
PS4='+ ${_plus:0:${#FUNCNAME[@]}}${FUNCNAME[0]} '
_plus='================='
bar
```

This works as follows. `${#FUNCNAME[@]}`  expands to the number of elements in the `FUNCNAME` array. As there is one element in the array for each function currently being called this is the function depth. This value is then used to select the first N characters from `$_plus`, which is set to a sequence of `=` signs. The number of characters in `$_plus` is a trade-off. You want enough to show your function nesting, but you also want to avoid the prompt getting stupidly long if you have deep nesting (perhaps you have recursive functions). Adding `${FUNCNAME[0]}` shows the current function. It is possible to use `$FUNCNAME` to refer to just the top element of the array, but it is clearer if you always access an arrary as an array and a scalar as a scalar.

With the OP's definitions of `foo`, `bar` and `baz` this gives you

```
$ bar
+  bar
+ =bar echo 'inside bar'
inside bar
+ =bar foo
+ ==foo echo 'inside foo'
inside foo
+ ==foo baz
+ ===baz echo 'inside baz'
inside baz
```

So the `+` at the start of the line tells you the eval/source/command substitution nesting level, the equal signs tell you the function nesting level and then you have the function name that you are in.

Adding `LINENO` and `BASH_SOURCE` are also things to consider adding to the PS4 prompt.